# EXCEL: compare cells in same column and calculate value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to calculate the profit based on the price from the supplier with the lowest price, and the price from the supplier with the biggest price. The assumption is that I will base my sale prices on the highest supplier prices.

As you can see in the table below, I have the columns

- Products
- Buy (price from my supplier)
- Sale % (the margin that I put on the supplier price to sell)
- The final price
- Finally, where I choose from which supplier I buy (BS) and which value I use as base to sell (PB).

Is there any way to calculate the profit for products A/B/C/... using PB-BS?

[image]

Comment: Please make this clearer. Are you trying to aggregate the different prices, or are these alternatives? See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to make the question clearer.

Comment: There may be a way.  **But** you need to show what you have tried for us to help you.  Review [ask] to see what a good question looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be using a PivotTable. The PivotTable will group the items together for you based on the product name, and can display the max and min for each name.

This would remove the need for the "BS"/"PB" column you have, and give you profit per product nice and neatly!

You would lay it out like so:

[image: pivot table]

To insert a pivot table, select your data and click Insert > PivotTable.

To populate the "Row Labels" and "Values" sections, simply drag the fields (top of the PivotTable window) into the sections as shown in my example.

By default, the "Values" items will be a sum. You can change this by clicking the small arrow by each item and choosing "Value Field Settings..." then either min or max.

You can then add the difference (or "profit") column yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You may try these **Array Formulas** which will require special key stroke **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of Enter alone.

In E2 (This will return PB or BS based on prices available for a product)

```
=IF(B2=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$12=A2,$B$2:$B$12)),"BS",IF(B2=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$12=A2,$B$2:$B$12)),"PB",""))
```

In F2 (This will return the profit based on BS and PB)

```
=IF(B2=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$12=A2,$B$2:$B$12)),D2-MIN(IF($A$2:$A$12=A2,$B$2:$B$12)),"")
```

Remember to confirm both the above formulas with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. :D 
I used the IFSUM function, that also worked.

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$12,$A$2:$A$12,A15,$E$2:$E$12,"PB")-SUMIFS($D$2:$D$12,$A$2:$A$12,A15,$E$2:$E$12,"BS")
```

I will test both your suggestions!

Regards